# LCD power down sequence

Tags: power-supply, lcd

I am trying to build my own gaming handheld. I chose a parallel RGB LCD (Samsung LTP500GV-F01). Using a boost converter by TI (TPS61085) I was able to generate all necessary voltages. (I know there's plenty of single-voltage-ready-to-use displays on the market but with every single LCD I had something to complain about.)

However the LCD's datasheet states to provide VGH after VGL. I understand this is necessary to prevent a latch-up and thus potentially burning the drivers. Attaching a capacitor to VGH, I was able to delay the build-up of VGH to a sufficient extend. The display is running fine.

Now, the datasheet also states to disable VGL last. Please see power down chart below (although I think it might be supposed to say ">5ms").

Will it likely be harmful to SHUT DOWN all voltages at the same time (I don't care about a visible discharge pattern on the screen) or VGH might even shut down last due to the capacitor attached?

[image: Timing diagram]

EDIT: I attached the LCD power circuitryand a section of the PCB layout

[image: LCD power circuitry]

[image: PCB layout]

Comment: They specify the 5 ms delay, which is non-trivial for the user to do, so there must be a reason. What's the mechanism of the problem they're trying to avoid. One of the issues with an LCD is that they are subject to long term damage if DC gets onto the panel. You might run your LCD for months before noticing such damage. Your call, do you use a power sequence control IC to do it cleanly, modify your solution to the requirements, work to understand from the panel manufacturer what damage might be caused, or just risk possible damage. Show us what you have so far, there might be an easy fix.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, you're propably right. Without the knowledge of the manufacturer it's impossible to tell if it's causing any long term damage... Since I have a MCU (3.3V) onboard the PCB I think maybe I could use this one to do the delay via a power switch or sometheing similar. However as you can see from the layout: I'm really struggeling with space constraints. Routing the great many of traces on a 2 layer board was already difficult enough. Any suggestions for compact parts that could siwtch 16V with a 3.3V logic?