# Load switch for sequenced application of voltage

Tags: power-supply, lcd

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/701797/lcd-power-down-sequence).

Now, in order to properly power up an LCD, the datasheet states to apply VGL first, then VGH and AVDD.

I want to do this with the circuitry below.
AVDD: 8 V, 30 mA max.
VGH:  15.5 V, 1.5 mA max.

A 3.3 V MCU is supposed to control U10.

It would be great if someone could tell me if the proposed circuitry is suited for the job, especially if the transistors I chose can do the job properly and efficiently. Can the inrush current be problematic?

[image: power sequencing circuitry]